# How do I check for a TNT explosion and stop that explosion from doing block damage? - 1.16.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So basically what I want to do is create my own fake explosion to break only certain blocks. The trigger for that fake explosion however is supposed to be an actual TNT explosion in close proximity which I want to not destroy any blocks. I have looked through many similar questions answered but the solutions to these problems were not transferable to my problem.

So in conclusion: I need to check if a TNT was lit and to then trigger my fake explosion right when the TNT explodes. The fake explosion should be the easiest part and I can do that already. Thanks in advance!